# Cant' save /etc/sudoers (Ubuntu)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-11.04

Question is;

I just setup AWS EC2 micro instance = Ubuntu 11.04 32bit - (ami-e9d81980)
All is running well. Added new user successfully and now want to give root access to new-user. So I did;

```
$ sudo visudo
new-user    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Problem is when I <kbd>ESC</kbd>`:wq` I get `[ Unknown Command ]` - Scratching my head. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you type `:help` to what you think is `vi`, do you get the usual `vim` help page? Or do you get some other pile of nonsense? I wonder if some horrible editor like `nano` or worse is being used in place of `vim`. Check `ls -l /usr/bin/editor /etc/alternatives/editor` to see what program is likely spawned by `visudo`.

Comment: +1: That `[ Unknown Command ]` sounds exactly like `nano`. Try `Ctrl-X` to exit and save your changes.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `sudo visudo` is a dangerous pattern because if you change the sudoers file such that you no longer have permission to run `sudo visudo` you can lock yourself out of your own system.  Use `sudo -s` or `sudo bash` first and then run `visudo` as the root user.  Test your changes before logging out of the root user.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet in Ubuntu is to switch your editor in alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

and select one of the `vim` options.

Answer (score 1):

This is sounds like you have no vim editor as default in your machine, inorder to use the vim as editor.

Execute below command, to make vim as editor

```
# export EDITOR=vim
```

And now try to edit the file `visudo /etc/sudoers` (Ubuntu)  and save by executing the vim commands <kbd>ESC</kbd> `!wq`